# Queue Using Deuce STM

Tags: java, multithreading, transactions, atomic, stm

I am new to Deuce STM and was wondering how do I go about implementing a queue using Deuce STM. Here is my current working implementation -

The Node class contains two fields - value and pointer to the next field.

```
public class STMQueue {

Node head, tail;

public STMQueue() {
    Node sentinel = new Node(-1);

    tail = sentinel;
    head = sentinel;
}

@Atomic
public void enq(int x) {
    Node node = new Node(x);
    tail.next = node;       
    tail = node;
}

@Atomic
public int deq() throws EmptyException{
    Node node = head.next;
    if(node == null) {
        throw new EmptyException();
    }
    int retVal = node.value;
    head = node;
    return retVal;
}

}
```

Is this the correct way of implementing it? Do we have to manually throw a Transaction Exception? If this is correct, then how do we measure the number of transactions aborted
or retried?

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with DeuceSTM. Having said that, a couple of notes:

- It appears your empty check is wrong; Should be `if (node == sentinel)` based on your constructor.
- [This message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/deuce-stm-developers/0T_GXb1GEgE/J7tqOGFdwRYJ) from Guy Korland leads me to believe that statistics aren't implemented; You'll have to modify the Context object it seems...